# Value-binding pattern with Swift structs

Tags: swift, struct, destructuring

As the Programming Swift book [describes](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Patterns.html), tuples can be destructured either in the assignment or by value-binding in a `switch`

```
let point = (3, 2)
switch point {
case let (x, y):
    print("The point is at (\(x), \(y)).")
}
let (a, b) = point
print("The point is at (\(a), \(b)).")
```

I can't find any mention of how to do the equivalent for structs. For example:

```
struct S {
    let a, b: Int
}
let s = S(a: 1, b: 2)

// This doesn't work:
// let (sa, sb): s
// 
// Outputs: error: expression type 'S' is ambiguous without more context
// let (sa, sb) = s
//                ^
```

Comment: Why would you need something like this, what's the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: That's right @Rob, I'll fix the question.

Comment: As others said, there isn’t a construct to do this for you, but if I needed this as a tuple (e.g. for `switch` pattern matching), I’d just `switch (s.a, s.b) { ... }`.

Comment: @Cristik it's a design hole that struck me as I was reading the language reference manual, that's why. Other languages with pattern matching and structs do allow it (e.g., [Rust](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch18-03-pattern-syntax.html#destructuring-structs)), so I was wondering if there was something I was missing.

Comment: I think this _is_ coming eventually. It's certainly been discussed in Evolution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This doesn't exist as such in the language.

One option is a helper computed property:

```
struct S {
    let i: Int
    let b: Bool
}

extension S {
    var destructured: (Int, Bool) {
        return (self.i, self.b)
    }
}

let s = S(i: 10, b: false)
let (i, b) = s.destructured
```

Of course, you have to manually keep that in sync. Possibly Sourcery could assist with that.

Answer (score 3):

Structs cannot be destructured in Swift.

Your tuple, `point = (3, 2)`, is of type `(Int, Int)`, which is part of why you are able to destructure it.

The type of your struct, `S`, is just `S`. Its variables, `a` and `b`, are not included in its type in the same literal way as they are for a tuple. A struct is simply a completely different kind of object, and this behavior does not exist for it.